# How do I modify existing fields in django that have a many to many relationship?

Tags: django, model, many-to-many, edit, create-view

I have a model with a many to many field (participant field in my Activity model, see below) that I want to edit using createview. However, I can only choose from the already existing entries, not create new ones. It is possible to do that in the admin site so there is a solution but I can't figure it out. I have tried to modify form_valid in views but with no succes. Any ideas how to add or modify a field that has a many to many relation?

```
views.py:
    #response=super(CreateTour,self).form_valid()
        #self.object.project=self.form.cleaned_data['participant']
class CreateTour(CreateView):

    form_class=CreateTourForm
    template_name='artdb/createtour.html'

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):

        context=super(CreateTour,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['formset']=CreateFormset()

        return context

    def form_valid(self,form):

        self.object=form.save(commit=False)
        for p in form.cleaned.data['participant']:
            ap=Person()
            ap.group=self.object
            ap.person=ap
            ap.save()

        return super(self).form_valid(form)
```

models.py:

```
class Activity(models.Model):

activity_name=models.CharField(max_length=200,default='no name')    
project=models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1)
participant=models.ManyToManyField(Person)
min_stage_area=models.IntegerField(default='2')
light_requirements=models.CharField(max_length=200,default='no requirements')
sound_engineer=models.CharField(max_length=200,default='not needed')
comment=models.ManyToManyField(Comment)

def __str__(self):
    return self.activity_name

class Meta:
    ordering = ('activity_name',)
```

forms.py:

```
  class CreateTourForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model=Activity
        fields=('activity_name','project','participant')
        widgets={'participant':CheckboxSelectMultiple,}

CreateFormset=modelformset_factory(
    Activity,
    fields=['activity_name','participant'],
    extra=1,
    widgets={
        'date':DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        }
    )
```

template:

```
{% extends "artdb/index.html" %}

{% block ct %}
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<div class="input-group">
  {% for fr in formset %}
    {{fr}}
  {% endfor %}
            <a>
            {{form}}
        </a>
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-success add-form-row">+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr></hr>
        <div class="row spacer">
          <input type="submit" value="save">
        </div>
</form>
{% endblock ct %}
```

Comment: If you want to add the ability to create new `Person` objects directly in your create tour page, use a [`modelformset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets). This will allow you to create multiple `Person` objects  and in your view you'll need to add them to the tour.

Comment: ok, I tested to add a modelformset, see edited forms.py but it gives me only dropdown alternatives of already added persons with no possibility to add a person. What am I missing?

Comment: But the model of your formset should be `Person` not `Activity` since you want to create a new `Person`. Also in your view you'll handle both the `ActivityForm` and your formset. A `CreateView` generic CBV isn't a good approach to mix these, write a function-based view.

Comment: ok, I will into it. What strikes me is that updating a m2m field should be a very common task in a db driven web framework like django, and yet it is very hard to get any information about it.